# Tabulator firing change event early

Tags: javascript, events, tabulator

I'm attempting to setup a datetime editor within Tabulator 5.0.0. When I begin editing my datetime cell, events occur in the following order

1. The cell's initial value is date: 04/19/1990
2. I click on the cell
3. The cell changes to show the format: "mm/dd/yyyy". "mm" is highlighted
4. I type in 05, which replaces the highlighted "mm". "dd" is now highlighted
5. I type in 21, which replaces the highlighted "dd". "yyyy" is now highlighted
6. I begin to type in the year, 2018. As soon as I type in the "2", a `change` event is fired, the cell loses focus and reverts back to its initial value of 04/19/1990.

The `change` event shouldn't fire until after I've finished typing the year. It appears to be firing as soon as I type the first digit of the year.

Here is the code for the columns header (case 5 within the switch is datetime):

```js
  buildHeaders(schema: TableSchema): any[] {
    var headers: any[] = [];

    headers = headers.concat({ formatter: "rowSelection", titleFormatter: "rowSelection", hozAlign: "center", frozen: true, download:false })
    schema.columns.forEach(c => {
      var h: any = {};
      h.title = c.alias;
      h.field = c.columnName;
      h.headerFilter = true;

      //set editors
      if (c.listItems.length > 0) {
        h.editor = "select";
        h.editorParams = { values: c.listItems };
      } else {
        switch (c.columnDataType) {
          case 1: { //string
            h.editor = "input";
            break;
          }
          case 2: { //integer
            h.editor = "number";
            h.editorParams =
            {
              min: Number.MIN_VALUE,
              max: Number.MAX_VALUE,
              step: 1
            };
            break;
          }
          case 3: { //decimal
            h.editor = "number";
            h.editorParams = {
              min: Number.MIN_VALUE,
              max: Number.MAX_VALUE,
              step: 1 / Math.pow(10, c.decimals)
            };
            break;
          }
          case 4: { //boolean
            h.formatter = "tickCross";
            h.hozAlign = "center";
            h.formatterParams = {
              allowTruthy: true,
            }
            h.cellClick = function(e, cell) {
              cell.setValue(!cell.getValue());
            }
            break;
          }
          case 5: { //date
            h.editor = this.dateEditor;
            h.formatter = "datetime";
            h.formatterParams = {
              inputFormat:"MM/dd/yyyy",
              outputFormat: "MM/dd/yyyy",
              invalidPlaceholder:"(invalid date)",
            }
            break;
          }

          default: {
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      //set sorters
      h.headerSortTristate = true;
      switch (c.columnDataType) {
        case 1: { //string
          h.sorter = "string";
          break;
        }
        case 2: { //integer
          h.sorter = "number";
          break;
        }
        case 3: { //decimal
          h.sorter = "number";
          break;
        }
        case 4: { //boolean
          h.sorter = "boolean";
          break;
        }
        case 5: { //date
          h.sorter = "date";
          break;
        }
        default: {
          break;
        }
      }
      headers = headers.concat(h);
    });
    return headers;
  }
```

Here is the code for the dateTime editor:

```js
  dateEditor  = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams){
    //cell - the cell component for the editable cell
    //onRendered - function to call when the editor has been rendered
    //success - function to call to pass the successfuly updated value to Tabulator
    //cancel - function to call to abort the edit and return to a normal cell
    //editorParams - params object passed into the editorParams column definition property

    //create and style editor
    var editor = document.createElement("input");

    editor.setAttribute("type", "date");

    //create and style input
    editor.style.padding = "3px";
    editor.style.width = "100%";
    editor.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

    var cellValue = cell.getValue();
    //Set value of editor to the current value of the cell
    editor.value = DateTime.fromFormat(cellValue, "MM/dd/yyyy").toFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")

    //set focus on the select box when the editor is selected (timeout allows for editor to be added to DOM)
    onRendered(function(){
        editor.focus();
        editor.style.height = "100%";
    });

    //when the value has been set, trigger the cell to update
    function successFunc(){
        success(DateTime.fromFormat(cell.getValue(), "MM/dd/yyyy").toFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    }
    
    editor.addEventListener("change", successFunc);
    editor.addEventListener("blur", successFunc);

    //return the editor element
    return editor;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have an event listener bound to the `change` event, which is triggered whenever the data is edited.

You simply need to remove the `change` listener and leave the `blur` listener as it and then it should work as desired